# Exception with socket windows. Read access violation

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock2

Just trying to open a socket with winsock. I get from visual studio an error stating that I have a read access violation on `ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);`

My whole code is there:

```
ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
 WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerr;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (wsaerr != 0)
    {
        printf("Server: The Winsock dll not found!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Server: The Winsock2 dll found \n");
    }
    /* SOCKET is simply a UINT, created because
 on Unix sockets are file descriptors(UINT) but not in windows
 so new type SOCKET was created */
    cout << AF_INET << endl ;
    cout << SOCK_STREAM << endl ;
    cout << IPPROTO_TCP << endl ;
    ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if(ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Server: Error initializing socket!n" << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    /* The SOCKADDR_IN structure is used by
 Win Sockets to specify an endpoint address
 to which the socket connects */
    sockaddr_in service,client ;
    service.sin_family = AF_INET;
    service.sin_port = htons(port);
    service.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    /* bind just links the socket
 with the sockaddr_in struct we initialized */
    if(bind(ListenSocket,(SOCKADDR*)&service,sizeof(service))==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Server: Error binding socket to port \n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    /* wait for incoming connections */
    if(listen(ListenSocket,10)==SOCKET_ERROR)
        printf("listen(): Error listening on socket %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    else
    {
        printf("Server: Waiting for connections...\n");
    }

    /* accept connections */

    printf("Server: Waiting for a client to connect...\n");
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    } else {
        wprintf(L"Client connected.\n");
        acceptConns();

    }
```

Would love to get some help on that because I cannot figure out why it's not working.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I'm creating that server in a thread with the following code. It would seem that this is the reason why I'm getting the error in the first place

```
DWORD WINAPI myThread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    tcp_server* server = (tcp_server*)lpParameter ;
    server->start_listening(); // The above function
    return 0 ;
}
.....

HANDLE myHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, server, 0,NULL);
```

Comment: Have you tried using instead the parameters returned by `getaddrinfo` as suggested by the official Microsoft tutorial?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I have but the getaddrinfo function is not defined

Comment: Which WinSock header are you including?

Comment: I'm including <winsock2.h>

Comment: Ah, turns out getaddrinfo is declared in <ws2tcpip.h>.
Have you included that one too?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Well now turns out the way they're using getadrrinfo on their website doesn't work. Wrong pointer type for hints and results. Starting to really hate winsock. Things are really easy on unix systems. Trying to fix that and I'll get back to you

Comment: This is what I get even though now result and hints are of type ADDRINFO : error C2664: 'getaddrinfo' : impossible to convert parameter 3 of type'tcp_server::ADDRINFOA *' to 'const ADDRINFOA *'
1>          Les types pointés n'ont aucun rapport entre eux ; conversion nécessitant reinterpret_cast, cast de style C ou cast de style fonction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82202/discussion-between-kaboissonneault-and-lonni-besancon).

Comment: I've checked some previous code that I had and I was creating sockets in that exact same way and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Apparently this has to do with the threading that I'm doing to launch this server. See edit

Comment: Could you please post the more or less complete definition of the `tcp_server` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a read access violation on `ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);`

There is no apparent read access happening on that line.

However, as the code you have shown (which is incomplete for diagnostic purposes) is inside a class method `tcp_server::start_listening()`, and `ListenSocket` is presumably a member of that class, and you are calling `start_listening()` via a `tcp_server` object pointer that is passed to a thread, it stands to reason that

1. the only reading that could be happening is the access of the implicit `this` pointer when assigning to the `ListenSocket` member.
2. the `tcp_server` object being pointed at most likely is not valid in memory by the time the thread calls `start_listening()` (or, at least when `socket()` is being called, since you do initialize `ListenSocket` beforehand).  If that were true, assigning to `ListenSocket` would be *undefined behavior*, which *CAN* cause access violation errors (amongst other kinds of errors, if any at all).

However, you did not show how you are creating your `server` object before calling `CreateThread()`, or what you do with the object after `CreateThread()` exits, so this reasoning is just an (educated) guess unless you show a more complete code example.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answer, I can show you a more complete code in an edit. Doing it ASAP (I'm on mobile for now)

Comment: You were completely right, just got it figured out: I was instantiating a new tcp_server object instead of using my class member that I was using when calling the thread. Thanks a lot for helping me :). Definitely deserves an upvote for figuring out the problem without the complete code and suggesting possible issues.